# The E 5.0 download is damaged when into Mac Sys22 (Sierra)

Tags: system-installation

This isn’t a question, instead is the only way I can find to report a problem.

Following multiple downloads of Elements 5 (elementaryos-5.0-stable-1.20181016.iso), into an old MacBkPro 2011 running any one of 5 Os X\macOS versions to do downloads with - unsuccessfully -  there seem to some disfunction between youse *(sic)* & me. :~\

Each .iso downloaded reports that “ . . disk image couldn’t be opened; Reason; no mountable file systems"

A 34 yr Mac-er with only light LinWin exposure, I suspect it may be me or my stuff not recognising what is contained in the .iso a.k.a. .dmg.

Having tried the usual Mac fixes for this problem, + some others, there is no success to report.

I (& others) am tired of APPL Inc suits stuffing up what was a half way decent OS. One that I could do 'big work' in, but now Mac-life is a struggle. Your aims for your OS sound similar what made the original Macintosh concept so easy to do work in, in that the OS soon disappears, and the work rises cleanly & alone to the surface.

Hope there’s an answer around. Looking fwd to learning E 5+ .

Cheers,
Jen,
Brisbane Oz

Comment: How can be a file damaged everytime, are you sure those file downloaded successfully? [Sorry i have this little knowledge of Mac, i don't have one]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to open the .iso on macOS? Or maybe your browser is automatically opening (mounting) it after download?

Either way, the iso for Elementary is not a data disk image that macOS can mount and read normally. It's an installation disk image that needs to be written to a USB key or CD-ROM and used to boot your machine from.

You'll need to write the image to a USB key with something like [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher), unless you're going to use something like VirtualBox or VMWare for testing Elementary.

There's a nice succinct [installation guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation) that might help.

Comment: Good answer. Might also want to mention the official installation guide: https://elementary.io/docs/installation

Comment: Good ideal @Veli-PekkaSamuliFinnilä, done.